# Open URL in intent

Tags: android, url, android-intent

In my application I receive a URL inserted by the user.  This URL can be - for example - `xx.sd`.  Using any web browser, this URL is a valid URL, but when try to open it by intent, a crash happens: `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=xx.sd }`.
I check this URL is valid URL by using this

```
Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(model.getTarget().getUrl()).matches()
```

and open intent by using this code

```
  Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse(model.getTarget().getUrl()));
  itemView.getContext().startActivity(i);
```

I know i can solve this issue by append `http` or `https` before URL if not exist but if my URL start with another protocol like `ftp` or `file` and other protocols. Can any one help me to handle this issue.

Comment: share your complete url for better ans

Comment: @Hasnain you can check issue by using any URL like `stackoverflow.com` or `fb.com` or any URL not start with `protocol` any `www`

Comment: share your own url here we are not going to make any special R&D on your problem

Comment: @Hasnain  check update

Comment: "intent crash happen intent not found exception" -- there is no such exception. Please edit your question and post the entire Java stack trace.

Comment: @CommonsWare check update `                                                             android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=xx.sd }
`

Comment: What is **model.getTarget()**?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you said this issue is really related to not well-formatted URL.

You can check for the **ACTION_VIEW** intent for the URL. First, this resolveActivity function check is there any application exists which can load URL. This will resolve the crash issue.

```
public void openWebPage(String url) {
        Uri webpage = Uri.parse(url);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, webpage);
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }else{
            //Page not found
        }
    }
```

**OR**, you can manage this by exception handling:

```
public void openWebPage(String url) {
        try {
            Uri webpage = Uri.parse(url);
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, webpage);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No application can handle this request. Please install a web browser or check your URL.",  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: When would **ActivityNotFoundException** be thrown?

Comment: If there is no application which can handle this ACTION_VIEW event to load the requested url at that time ActivityNotFoundException be thrown. To not let it happen, use first function in which there is check for resolveActivity for the intent action type.

Comment: There can be an Android device which doesn't handle **ACTION_VIEW** intent?

Answer (score 0):

Add un try-catch and call-again, such as:

```
public boolean startOpenWebPage(String url) {
    boolean result = false;
    if (!url.startsWith("http://") && !url.startsWith("https://"))
        url = "http://" + url;

    Uri webpage = Uri.parse(url);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, webpage);

    try {
        startActivity(intent);
        result = true;
    }catch (Exception e){
        if (url.startsWith("http://")){
            startOpenWebPage(url.replace("http://","https://"));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```